# Prove that any unbounded sequence has a subsequence that diverges to $∞$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

To prove that any unbounded sequence has a subsequence that diverges to ∞, is it enough to say that you can take a subsequence $(a_{m(k)})$ where $m(k)=k$, as you know that this diverges to infinity, you are done?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of an unbounded sequence that does not diverge to infinity:
$$1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, \dots.$$
Do you see the problem in your thinking? Remember, diverging to infinity means for all $M > 0$ there is an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $a_n \geq M$.

Here's a hint on how do this correctly. Given a term $a_{n_k}$ there must be an $m > n_k$ such that $a_{n_k} + 1< a_{m}$ otherwise $a_n$ would be bounded. Then choose $n_{k+1} = m$.

Comment: Oops! I wrongly assumed that an unbounded sequence must diverge to infinity. I see for this case what I must do, however I don't quite get the general case. Why does your statement imply boundedness?

Comment: None of my statements imply boundedness. I'm not sure what you are asking. Try to apply the hint I gave to the sequence I also gave. Convince yourself that it works in general (If you use the hint, you won't get 1, 2, 3, 4,... but you'll get something that still works).

Comment: See if this rewording helps. Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a sequence unbounded (from above, I presume). Note that every tail of this sequence contains arbitrarily large terms. I'll show how to pick $a_{n_{1}},$ $a_{n_{2}},$ $a_{n_{3}}, \; \ldots$ so that $a_{n_{k}} \rightarrow \infty$ when $k \rightarrow \infty.$ (In fact, I'll even arrange it so that this subsequence is strictly increasing.) Choose $n_1$ so that $a_{n_{1}}>42.$ Choose $n_2 > n_1$ so that $a_{n_{2}}>a_{n_{1}} + 42.$ Choose $n_3 > n_2$ so that $a_{n_{3}}>a_{n_{2}} + 42.$ Keep going. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** Incidentally, $42$ can be replaced throughout by any fixed positive real number, but we can't omit this part entirely (i.e. we can't replace $42$ with $0)$ because we need to prevent the possiblity of $a_{n_{k}}$ increasing like a function approaching a horizontal asymptote from below.